# SignalR disconnecting every few minutes after the tab is backgrounded

Tags: javascript, .net, .net-core, signalr

I'm using SignalR for communication between a Vue.js frontend and dotnet backend.

When you background the frontend tab after a (seemingly random) amount of time the connection gets disconnected. Because I'm using auto reconnect the socket is then reconnected, but then until the tab is re-focused the socket will continue to get disconnected every couple of minutes putting it in a reconnecting loop.

[image]

A few things:

- Seems to happen in all browsers but Firefox
- When running both the frontend and backend locally, there's no issue
- Running the frontend locally but backend remotely does cause the issue
- Neither application are running on IIS
- Kestrel timeouts have been set to an hour (just in case)
- The initial disconnect that causes the reconnects to start looping doesn't happen at a consistent time, just somewhere around the 5-10 minute mark
- No errors are being thrown by either end

Client side code is extremely basic:

```
 this.connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl(this.url)
        .withAutomaticReconnect()
        .build()
```

Server side code is similarly basic:

```
 public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        //Create client code here

        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        if(exception != null) _logger.LogErrorToFile(exception.Message);
        _logger.LogInformationToFile($"Client with id: {GetConnectionId()} disconnected.{GetUsername()}");
        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
```

Comment: This might help https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/4536

Comment: Chrome made an update earlier this year that stops connections when they are no in focus after about 5 minutes. The issue/fix that Nirbhay commented is actually for the ASP.NET version (2.4.2) and not compatible with .NET CORE. Here is the issue that was raised for .NET CORE - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/31079

Comment: @FrankM That thread was exactly what I needed, thanks

Comment: @Coffee glad that helps you. I will post as an answer. Please mark if you get have time in case others look for the same.

Comment: @Coffee Please mark Frank's answer to display ur problem as solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome made an update earlier this year that stops connections when they are not in focus after about 5 minutes. The issue/fix that Nirbhay commented is actually for the ASP.NET version (2.4.2) and not compatible with .NET CORE. Here is the issue that was raised for .NET CORE - github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/31079